# how to center data in google charts table that is dynamically

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using the table in google charts.  All of the data in the table is aligned right.  I need to align the text in the center.  I am building the table dynamically so I cannot apply the set cell method:

```
 data.setCell(1, 1, 25000, '$25,000', {'className': 'bold-font center-text'});
```

I would like to apply the class name without applying the 25000 and $25000 values. Something like:
     data.setCell(1, 1, '', '', {'className': 'bold-font center-text'});

I also don't want to apply this just to the first cell but entire table.

**In conclusion**, how do I center all of the text in a table?

Comment: Can't you just run a loop through all your data after dynamically creating it to set the property with the code you have above? I see no reason you can't apply it using that method.

Answer (score 8):

add custom css

add this code to your page

```
<style>
.google-visualization-table-td {
text-align: center !important;
}
</style>
```

"!important" is necessary to override google's left/right align for number/text.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative answer for those of you out there who are trying to accomplish the same thing, but using Angular and Ionic.

I had to put this bit of css in the *.scss file that is associated with the *.html file where the chart is to be rendered:

```
::ng-deep td[class^='google-visualization-table'] {
    text-align: center !important;
    }
```

The strange caret after the "class" is there to apply the style only to td elements that begin with the string 'google-visualization-table'.  Depending on what type of data your td contains, the class name might be simply "**google-visualization-table-td**", or it might be "**google-visualization-table-type-number google-visualization-table-td**", etc, so a flexible css statement like this is necessary.

Also, I've heard that ng:deep is deprecated, but this still works (as of late 2021).  Probably good to do it a different way in the future, though.