# How to center the text in the header row in google charts table

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I have a very similar problem from the following question:
[how-to-center-data-in-google-charts-table-that-is-dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422026/how-to-center-data-in-google-charts-table-that-is-dynamically)

to center align all rows data I use:

```
<style>
.google-visualization-table-td {
text-align: center !important;
}
</style>
```

but that doesnt align the header row. is there a similar way to align that header?

Comment: The header row is usually < th >. Adding your html will help with this issue.

Comment: @Harley you are actually right, replacing td for th does the trick. pretty new to all this thank you!